# How to test Hive CRUD queries from Shell scripting

Tags: shell, testing, hive

i am creating a shell script, which should execute The HIVE basic queries and assert that with expected result.
from where should i start in shell scripting.?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer, 
one thing we can do is, create a hql file which contain basic queries to be test and triggered hql file through beeline(as i was using) in bash file.